# How do I access a variable from the code behind of another page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an  index.aspx (index.aspx.cs) which will include the body.aspx (body.aspx.cs) using `Server.execute("body.aspx");`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;

public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string text1 = "abc";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        

    }

}
```

In index.aspx.cs, there is a variable `text1` which I want to use in body.aspx.cs, how to do that?

Comment: Why not use master pages instead of 'injecting' your pages together manually?

Comment: Maybe its impossible, and maybe its better to follow the asp.net way when you programming on dot net.

Comment: i set up a masterpage, and inserted some content page, but how to view the page in browser, that is a .master?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're thinking of ASP.NET the wrong way. I guess you started as a Windows Developer.

ASP.NET Forms are not like Windows Forms.

You have to understand that the ASP.NET page only lives until the request is being served. And then it "dies".

You cannot pass variables from/to pages the same way you do with Windows Forms.

If you want to access contents from another page. Then this page MUST store that piece of information inside a SESSION object and then you access that session object from a different page and get the value that you want.

Let me give you an example:

Page 1:

```
public string text1 = "abc";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          Session["FirstName"] = text1;
    }
```

Page 2:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string text1;          
    text1 = Session["FirstName"].ToString();
}
```

That's how you pass values between pages that are not linked together.

Also, you can pass values using by modifying the Query string (add variables to the URL).

Example:

Page 1: (button click event)

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Webform2.aspx?Name=" +
    this.txtName.Text + "&LastName=" +
    this.txtLastName.Text);
}
```

Page 2:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   this.txtBox1.Text = Request.QueryString["Name"];
   this.txtBox2.Text = Request.QueryString["LastName"];
}
```

this is how you should pass variables between pages

Also, if you want a value to be shared between ALL visitors of your website. Then you should consider using Application instead of Session.

Answer (score 2):

If you mark the variable as [`static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx), it ceases to become a property of a particular *instance* of the page and becomes a property of the *type* of page.

You can then access it as `index.text1` from anywhere that can see the `index` class.

However, this means that the value is then shared between every instance of this page: if it is changed by an instance of the page (or by any other class that can now see it), subsequent page loads will reflect the changed value.

If you don't want this - if this variable should be different between each instance of the page - then what you want isn't possible. ASP.NET pages don't *exist* other than while they're being generated by the server, so there *is* no page for you to get this value from.

If this value is never meant to change, mark it as [`const`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx) and you don't have to worry about things changing it.