# How do I send a string or value from the Site.Master.cs to my Default.aspx.cs to the value/string in a label/textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Thanks for reading.
I want to set the value obtained in Label1 (in Site.Master.cs) to be passed on to Label2 (in Default.aspx.cs). I want to use it as a value to cross reference data in an SQL db later on in the project.

I just can't seem to get my head around this one.

In Site.Master.cs

```
namespace flexpoolWeb
{
    public partial class SiteMaster : MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var windowsIdentity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;

            if (windowsIdentity == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("WindowsIdentity is null");

            string nameWithoutDomain = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Split('\\').Last();
            //serverside code httpContext haalt ingelogde gebruiker op in de sessie.

            Label1.Text = String.Format(nameWithoutDomain);

            Label2.Text = MyMaster.UserName;

        }
        public string UserName
        {
            get { return Label1.Text; }
            set { Label1.Text = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

In Default.aspx.cs:

```
namespace flexpoolWeb
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page //instead of : Page
    {
        private SiteMaster MyMaster => ((SiteMaster)Master);

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit: added the answer from Skye MacMaster**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045188/access-variable-from-code-behind-of-another-page)

Comment: Your concept looks correct. Are you getting an error in Page_Load1? Maybe something about UserName not being part of Master? or is the value just not coming through?

Comment: You have to cast Master to the correct type.
Try: Label2.Text = ((Site)Master).UserName
Personaly I would store it in the Session, then it is availlable everywhere in you site.

Answer (score 0):

Your master page is derived from MasterPage. So you need to type cast Master from MasterPage to whatever the name your master is. I'm guessing Site or SiteMaster. Also, I usually create a private property to avoid having a bunch of ugly typecasting.

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private SiteMaster MyMaster => ((SiteMaster) Master);

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label2.Text = MyMaster.UserName;
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the code you supplied in the default.aspx.sc file. Still no text or value in the Label2 textbox. ( I edited my question for current state of code). What could it be?

Comment: First, Page_Load1 should be Page_Load or the autowireup probably won't work and Page_Load1 will never be called. Second, have you configured some form or authentication? If not HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name will be an empty string and thus Label2.Text will be set to empty string.

Comment: Hi Skye, changing Page_Load1 to Page_Load in the Default.aspx.cs gives me an error:  "Type _Default already defines a member calles ' Page_load' with same parameter types. "

Comment: You can only have one Page_Load. Move the code from Page_Load1 to Page_Load and get rid of Page_Load1.

Comment: Tried it. Adding Label2.Text = MyMaster.UserName; to Page_Load in Site.Master.cs gives me error telling Label2 and MyMaster do not exsist in current context.